# Convert reference primitives to generic type

Tags: c#, object, methods, parameters, type-conversion

I know the title is confusing so I'll try to explain better.  Here's basically what I want to do inside a method:

```
if (record["id"] != DBNull.Value) _id = Convert.ToInt32(record["id"]);
else id = -1;
```

I want this to work for multiple types that I have stored in my database.  (So if it's a string it converts it to a string and so forth).  Any way to do this is fine, and I was trying to do it with a method.  I got this far but C# won't automatically convert int to object.  ideas?

```
    private void Load(ref object var, object obj, object def)
    {
        if (var is int)
        {
            var = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
        }
    }

   int _id;
   Load(ref _id, record["id"], -1);
```

Just to clarify, my error is "cannot convert from ref int to ref object".
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Convert.ChangeType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx) and make your method generic:

```
private void Load<T, U>(out T value, U obj, T defaultValue)
{
    if (obj is DBNull)
       value = defaultValue;
    else
        value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
}
```

Now you can just use it like this (simplified example, not sure what you need `def` for):

```
int id;
object foo = 42;
Load(out id, foo, 1);
```

Comment: That still gives me the same error, because the parameter types do not match.

Comment: Also, def was just a default value.

Comment: Ok so what happens if foo == DBNull.Value?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know if ChangeType covered that or how it worked.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First off, `var` is a reserved word in C# 3.0 and above (VS 2008 and later).

More to the point, I'd try setting this up as a generic; that way, your method can discover the true types of the variables you pass in, and work with them case-by-case as if they were strongly typed:

```
private void Load<TVar, TSet>(ref TVar var, TSet obj, TVar def)
{
    //this is a little heavy-handed, but in pretty much any situation where 
    //this can fail, you just want the basic type.
    try
    {
       if (var is IConvertible && obj is IConvertible)
          var = (TVar)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(TVar));
       else
          var = (TVar)obj; //there may just be an explicit operator
    }
    catch(Exception) 
    {
       var = def; //defined as the same type so they are always assignable
    }
}
```